# Why is there a padding around flexbox containers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There seems to be a padding around the container and in between the two columns. How do I get rid of them?

I tried setting margin and padding to 0 but it did not work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5XJJ.jpg

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.flexbox img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media all and (max-width: 650px) {
  .flexbox {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 651px) {
  .col-1,
  .col-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main id="container">
  <div class="flexbox col-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/f00/000?text=1" />
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox col-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/0f0/000?text=2" />
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox col-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/06f/000?text=3" />
  </div>
</main>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's why it happens because img is inline. Add `display: block;` to `.flexbox img`

Comment: thank you @GrzegorzT. That worked, and I added margin: 0; to html to get rid of the borders.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML every Element has default properties. I think this padding exists because of the `<div>` Element. To remove it, you can set

```
.flexbox { padding: 0 }
```

Comment: @Druckles thx for the correction.